# How to import local .sql file to pythonanywhere database?

Tags: python, mysql, pythonanywhere

I have an application deployed in **pythonanywhere** everything is running fine till now. Now I want to connect my app with the database as my application needs to interact with it. My **.sql** file is stored in my computer.
 How can I import it to the project's database in the pythonanywhere server ?

I have tried connecting that database using MySQL Workbench so that I can import from there but Workbench wasn't able to connect to that server.

Answer (score 1):

There are two helpful instructions on PythonAnywhere, one about [Backing up (and restoring) MySQL databases](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/MySQLBackupRestore) other about [accessing your MySQL database from outside PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/) (you can do it using ssh tunnel).

Comment: I had followed the 2nd step 1st but there's coming a connection error but now I tried with the 1st one. but while importing it's showing this error ```ERROR 1419 (HY000) at line 88: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_
trust_function_creators variable)```